# EVP_MD_CTX "error: storage size of ‘ctx’ isn’t known"

Tags: c, openssl

My system is Ubuntu16.04 LTS. when I use the OpenSSL `EVP_MD_CTX`, this error appeared. Can anyone help me?

---

***CODE***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
int main()
{
    int ret,inlen,outlen=0;
    unsigned long e=RSA_3;
    char data[100],out[500];
    EVP_MD_CTX md_ctx, md_ctx2;
    ...
}
```

***ERROR***:

```
root@ubuntu:/work/test# gcc evp_openssl_test.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o
evptestevp_openssl_test.c: In function ‘main’:
evp_openssl_test.c:13:19: error: storage size of ‘md_ctx’ isn’t known
    EVP_MD_CTX md_ctx,md_ctx2;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are using OpenSSL 1.1.0 which made this structure (and many others) opaque - which means you cannot stack allocate it. Instead do this:

```
EVP_MD_CTX *md_ctx;

md_ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
if (md_ctx == NULL)
    ...
...
EVP_MD_CTX_free(md_ctx);
```

Comment: thanks, I modified the code in this way and it started working.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error but with EVP_CIPHER_CTX

```
error: storage size of ‘ctx’ isn’t known
       EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
```

I solved with this:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
```

I hope this helps somebody with the same problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the reference of [link](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/openssl-error-storage-size-of-ctx-isnt-known-duplicate)

Convert your code to the following:

```
EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, mess1, strlen(mess1));
EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, mess2, strlen(mess2));
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
```