# AES cbc 256 decryption failed in C openssl

Tags: c, openssl, aes

I'm trying to write AES encryption/decryption program in C using openssl. However, when I tried to decrypt the message, I got error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length.

```
  void aes_encrypt(unsigned char* in, int inl, unsigned char *out, int* len, unsigned char * key){
      unsigned char iv[16] = "encryptionIntVec";
      EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
          EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
  
      EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);  
   
      *len = 0;
      int outl = 0;
  
      EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, out+*len, &outl, in+*len, inl);
      *len+=outl;
  
      int test = inl>>4;
      if(inl != test<<4){
          EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&ctx,out+*len,&outl);  
          *len+=outl;
      }
      EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
  }
   
   
  void aes_decrypt(unsigned char* in, int inl, unsigned char *out, unsigned char *key){
      unsigned char iv[16] = "encryptionIntVec";
      EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
      EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
      
      int result; 
  
      result = EVP_DecryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv); 
      if(result > 0) {
          printf("passed\n");
      } else {
          printf("failed\n");
      }
      int len = 0;
      int outl = 0;
   
      result = EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, out+len, &outl, in+len, inl);
      if(result > 0) {
          printf("passed\n");
      } else {
          printf("failed\n");
      }
      len += outl;
       
      result = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&ctx, out+len, &outl); 
      if(result > 0) {
          printf("passed\n");
      } else {
          printf("failed\n");
          ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
      } 
      len+=outl;
      out[len]=0;
      EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
  }
  
  int main()
  {

      unsigned char content[400];

      unsigned char key[] = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";

         /******************Block 1*****************************/
      unsigned char en[400],de[400],base64[400], base64_out[400];
      int len; 
      memset(content, 0,400);
      memset(en, 0, 400);
      memset(de, 0, 400);
      memset(base64, 0,400);
      memset(base64_out, 0, 400);
      strcpy((char *)content, "loc: 123.2132412, -39.123142");
      
      printf("%d %s\n", strlen((const char*)content), content);
          //encrypt content
      aes_encrypt(content,strlen((const char*)content), en, &len, (unsigned char*)key);
      
          //base64 encode ciphertext
      int encode_str_size = EVP_EncodeBlock(base64, en, len);
      printf("%d %s\n", encode_str_size, base64);
      
          //base64 decode
      int length = EVP_DecodeBlock(base64_out, base64, strlen((const char*)base64));
      while(base64[--encode_str_size] == '=') length--;
      
          //decrypt 
      aes_decrypt(base64_out, length, de, (unsigned char*)key);
      printf("%d %s\n", strlen((const char*)de), de);
  
      
      /***********************Block 2*******************************/
      unsigned char msg_out[400];
      unsigned char msg[400] = "6hKe8RGg+4p1N1R6Y9aaTovxLtuH115JoWUO8plrAJE=";
      unsigned char result[400];
  
      int l = EVP_DecodeBlock(msg_out, msg, strlen((const char*)msg));
      if(strcmp((const char*)msg, (const char*)base64)==0) {
          printf("match\n");
      }
      if(strcmp((const char*)en, (const char*)msg_out)==0) {
          printf("match\n");
      }
      while(msg[--encode_str_size] == '=') l--;
      
      aes_decrypt(msg_out, l, result, (unsigned char*)key);
      printf("%d %s\n", strlen((const char*)result), result);
          return 0;
  }
```

In block 1 of main function, I encrypted, base64 encoded, base64 decoded, decrypted, then got the exactly the same String as it was, and produced NO error.
However, in the block 2, I directly used the base64 encoded string which was produced from block 1, decoded and decypted, but an error occurred at `result = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&ctx, out+len, &outl);` that was `error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length`.

If I printed the decrypted string anyways, it is  `loc: 123.2132412, -39.123142^D^D^D^D`, there are four '^D' appended at the end. I compared strings, both `match` was printed, which means the ciphertexts that was decoded from base64 with the one(`en`) in block 1 were the same. (NOTE: same key, same IV)

Any ideas why it failed?

Comment: Did you try without the `if(inl != test<<4)` test in aes_encryt ? In order to always call `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex` function.

Comment: @JoëlHecht the encryption part actually works well. I tried remove if condition, ran into encryption failure

Comment: Check your version of openSSL. Beginning with 1.1.0, you can no longer use `EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;` as a variable with automatic storage duration. This type and many more, were made opaque types. You now must declare a pointer, e.g. `EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;` and allocate for the context with `ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();` See [EVP_MD_CTX "error: storage size of 'ctx' isn't known"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662733/evp-md-ctx-error-storage-size-of-ctx-isn-t-known/42666983)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using version *OpenSSL 3.0.0-dev* and therefore had to modify the code for the reasons described in David C. Rankin's comment. The problem occurs even after these changes.

Debugging reveals that the length of the Base64 decoded data in block 2 is determined incorrectly with `l = 0x21 = 33`. The correct value is `l = 0x20 = 32`.
This is because in block 2, when determining the length of the Base64 decoded data *without* the `0x00` padding bytes (added by [`EVP_DecodeBlock()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_EncodeBlock.html)) with

```
while (msg[--encode_str_size] == '=') l--;
```

the value for `encode_str_size` *already changed in block 1* is used. The fix is to apply the *current* value for the length of the Base64 encoded data, e.g.

```
encode_str_size = strlen((const char*)msg);
```

Then decryption for block 2 works on my machine.

---

Note that [`EVP_DecodeBlock()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_EncodeBlock.html) always returns the Base64 decoded data with a length equal to an integer multiple of `3`, padded with `0x00` values if necessary.
The *actual* length of the data can therefore also be determined with `msg_out` and `l` alone. `l` specifies the length *including* the `0x00` padding bytes, so that only the number of the `0x00` padding bytes has to be subtracted from `l`.
Thus, `msg` and `encode_str_size` are actually not needed (although both can be used, since the number of `=` padding bytes is equal to the number of `0x00` padding bytes).

---

As already mentioned in the comment by Joël Hecht, the `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()` call is necessary, which among other things performs the padding (PKCS7).
In the currently posted code, this only occurs if the length of the plaintext does not equal an integer multiple of 16 bytes (the AES block size) which is satisfied for the test data.
However, for a plaintext whose length is a multiple of 16 bytes, `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()` is not called, so padding is not performed, resulting in a decryption failure in `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex()`.

---

Apart from the Base64 encoding, the OpenSSL documentation [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#Setting_it_up) provides a complete example for `EVP_aes_256_cbc()`, which could be used for comparison.

Comment: Nice catch!! That was my oversight.. Completely forgot to update that encode_str_size. I really appreciate!!!